# Azure Notification Hub Xamarin Register Multiple For Multiple Templates

Tags: ios, templates, azure, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I need some help with registering an iOS device for multiple templates with Azure Notification Hubs.

Registering for a single template works fine but it seems like when registering for multiple templates from a single device, the second template that is registered for always works fine and the first template that is registered for does not work correctly.

I found something the other day saying that each template had to have a unique PNS Handle but even getting (what I think might be) 2 unique PNS Handles does not seem to work.

Templates #1:

```
{"aps":{"title":"$(emergencyTitle)","alert":"$(emergencyMessage)","tags":"$(emergencyTags)"}}
```

Template #2:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1,"title":"$(regularTitle)","alert":"$(regularMessage)","inAppMessage":"$(regularMessage)","tags":"$(regularTags)"}}
```

The code below gets called twice (which I was hoping would get 2 unique PNS Handles). Each time, it saves the `deviceToken` in a variable so that I can register the 2 templates with them:

```
if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0)) {
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new Foundation.NSSet()));

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
} else {
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);
}
```

Then the following stripped down code makes the call to the notification hubs to try and register the 2 templates:

```
Hub = Hub ?? new WindowsAzure.Messaging.SBNotificationHub(Constants.ConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubPath);

// App.PushNotificationPnsHandles is a Dictionary<string, object> that holds an 'emergency' or 'regular' key and the deviceTokens
// Constants.EmergencyNotificationTemplate and Constants.RegularNotificationTemplate hold the template strings

Hub.UnregisterAllAsync((NSData)App.PushNotificationPnsHandles["emergency"], error => {
    Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync((NSData)App.PushNotificationPnsHandles["emergency"], "EmergencyTemplate", Constants.EmergencyNotificationTemplate, System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(90).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")), new NSSet(), errorCallback => { });
});

Hub.UnregisterAllAsync((NSData)App.PushNotificationPnsHandles["regular"], error => {
    Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync((NSData)App.PushNotificationPnsHandles["regular"], "RegularTemplate", Constants.RegularNotificationTemplate, System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(90).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")), new NSSet(), errorCallback => { });
});
```

Again, if I make a single call to register for the emergency template everything works great. If I make a single call to register for the regular template everything works great.

If I try to register for the emergency template first and then the regular template, then I send an emergency push notification, a push notification does indeed arrive at the phone but it contains no text in any of the variables... Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Edit: Looking in the Notification Hub debug window in Visual Studio, I can see 2 registrations, each with a different Registration ID but with the same PNS Identifier. If this is the case then I am not sure how to get unique identifiers for each template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A specific app on a specific device is identified by one particular PNS handle. You can't have multiple different PNS handles for the same app on the same device.
2. Don't use `UnregisterAllAsync()` if you don't want to actually delete all registrations. Just use `RegisterTemplateAsync()`, it will create **or update** a template registration.
3. If you want to use multiple templates, you have to **distinguish the registrations with different tags**, not with different PNS handles, since the PNS handle is always identical.

So, what you have to do is:

1. Don't get the PNS handle twice, but only once, since it is always the same anyways.
2. Remove the calls to `UnregisterAllAsync()`, `RegisterTemplateAsync()` is sufficient.
3. Pass at least one tag to `RegisterTemplateAsync()` instead of an empty `NSSet`, and make sure the tag is different for each of your template registrations, e.g. "template:emergency" and "template:regular".
4. If you want to send a "regular" notification, provide the "template:regular" tag to address the right registration, if you want to send an "emergeny" notification, use the "template:emergency" tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I thought that a specific template could be targeted by using the word `regularMessage` or what ever in the push notification message but it sounds like even with multiple templates, you still have to use tags to target one or the other. Appreciate your answer and will mark it as such as soon as I can implement it this morning.

Comment: Unfortunatley, the template name you provide as the second argument is really just a label, you can't do anything with it, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30026467/594074 ...

Comment: It seems to be working great! Strangely, I do not have to use tags when sending to different templates on Android but it seems like I do have to on iOS. Might look into if the way I have made the template is an issue or something but I am happy with this, given the time frame. Thanks again.

Comment: I can confirm similar behaviour. Android OK, iOS template distribution seems to prefer a second template if the tag is shared.